# FX5200 black windows

Tags: system-installation

I can boot from the installation image into elementary OS Freya or Luna, but all window appear as a black boxes to me, I cannot see any content.

It's dell laptop, Pentium 4 mobile. 2GB of RAM and AMD FX5200 Mobile GPU.

Is there a way (e.g. a boot option) to make graphics work on an installation stage?

Answer (score 2):

Hold down shift at boot, choose other options, "nomodeset" and then choose the "install" option!